# Edit form in flutter with getx

Tags: flutter-getx

im new for both flutter and getx and i'm trying to make edit **Form** with getx , but i get **Null** .. how to fill TextEditingController after api response

```js
class EditMarketerController extends GetxController {
  final DashboardApiProvider dashboardApiProvider;
  EditMarketerController({required this.dashboardApiProvider});

  MarketerToEdit marketer = MarketerToEdit();
  TextEditingController usernameController = 
  TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController emailController = 
  TextEditingController();
 
  @override
  void onInit() {
    _getMarketer();  //----- **api call**
    // Wait until the completion of the data call and then fill ↓↓↓

    final usernameController = TextEditingController(text: 
        marketer.username);
    final emailController = TextEditingController(text: 
        marketer.email);
    super.onInit();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use callBack in your _getMarketer method like this.

```
_getMarketer({Function? callBack}){

/// implement your api and put callBack in your api call success like this

 if(callBack != null){
  callBack(); 
 }
}
```